# Cannot read property 'getActiveIndex' of undefined ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i Want to get the active index of my slider but have an error.

html :

```
  <ion-slides *ngIf="DonneeChaines && !IsLoading"  [options]= "slideOpts" #slides (ionSlideDidChange)="onSlideChanged($event)">
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of DonneeChaines">
    <img src="./assets/img/chaines/{{item.sCodeChaine}}.png">
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

ts

```
@ViewChild('slides', { static: true}) slides: IonSlides;

onSlideChanged(event) {
console.log('event change', event);
this.slides.getActiveIndex().then((index) => {
  console.log('index est', index);
});
}
```

console :

[image]

someone to help me?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

I found something that might interest you.
Your view child will not be initialized if your component is wrapped with a if condition.

Here is what I had and was not working :

```
<ion-content *ngIf="handful">
<ion-slides style="height: 100%" #slides pager (ionSlideReachEnd)="onLastSlide()" (ionSlideDidChange)="handleSlideChange()">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let card of handful.cards" >
        <ion-card class="card flex col justify-center">
            <img *ngIf="card.media" class="w-full" style="height: 250px; object-fit: cover" [src]="card.media" >
            <ion-card-content class="h-full" [innerHTML]="card.description"></ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
<ion-fab *ngIf="!currentUser.hadSeenTutorial" class="fab-tutorial" vertical="center" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button (click)="presentTutorial()">
        <ion-icon name="help-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>
```

You can see that my content is not set til my handful is not defined.
That means nothing INSIDE the component will be initialized neither.
And that explain why the viewchild is undefined on the call of this function :

```
(ionSlideDidChange)="handleSlideChange()"
```

Here's the workaround I found to fix it :

```
ion-content>
<ion-slides #slides style="height: 100%" pager (ionSlideReachEnd)="onLastSlide()" (ionSlideDidChange)="handleSlideChange()">
    <ng-template [ngIf]="handful">
        <ion-slide  *ngFor="let card of handful.cards" >
            <ion-card class="card flex col justify-center">
                <img *ngIf="card.media" class="w-full" style="height: 250px; object-fit: cover" [src]="card.media" >
                <ion-card-content class="h-full" [innerHTML]="card.description"></ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
        </ion-slide>
    </ng-template>
</ion-slides>
<ion-fab *ngIf="!currentUser.hadSeenTutorial" class="fab-tutorial" vertical="center" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button (click)="presentTutorial()">
        <ion-icon name="help-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>
```

Long story short, first, init your slider, then use the if inside a ng-template.
This way, your slider will always be initialized at startup.

Answer (score 0):

another solution could be the following.

file.scss.

```
.hide{
    display:none !important;
}
```

file ionic html.

```
<ion-content  [ngClass]="{'hide': !handful}">
<ion-slides style="height: 100%" #slides pager (ionSlideReachEnd)="onLastSlide()" (ionSlideDidChange)="handleSlideChange()">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let card of handful.cards" >
        <ion-card class="card flex col justify-center">
            <img *ngIf="card.media" class="w-full" style="height: 250px; object-fit: cover" [src]="card.media" >
        <ion-card-content class="h-full" [innerHTML]="card.description">
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
<ion-fab *ngIf="!currentUser.hadSeenTutorial" class="fab-tutorial" vertical="center" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button (click)="presentTutorial()">
        <ion-icon name="help-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>
```